# Perl CGI, using system() to launch ssh and pass sanitized variables

Tags: debian, perl, cgi

I'm looking for a way to have perl launch a program with variables taken from the previous webpage.
Here's my horrible perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
my $guy = param('number');
$guy =~ s/\D//g;
if ($guy == 0){
    die("Please enter number for employee");
}
my $sides = param('clock');
my $finger =  param('finger');

if ($sides == "left"){
system($finger, $guy |  "sudo ssh root@172.16.4.10: fprintd-enroll -f");
exit 0;
}
 if ($sides == "right"){
 system($finger, $guy |  "sudo ssh root@172.16.4.11: fprintd-enroll -f");
exit 0;
}
```

But I keep getting errors like:
    "An error occurred while reading CGI reply (no response received)"

Is there a better way to do this kind of thing between two debian boxes?
Is there a way to get the 'ssh' way to work?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Based on the advice bellow I changed the code up over the past week but I'm still not quite there.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                              
use CGI qw(:standard -debug);                                                 
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);                          
use Net::SSH2;                                                                
use strict;                                                                    
my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();                                                    
my $q = new CGI;                                                              
my $style = get_style();                                                                                                                                  
my $guy = param('number');                                                    
$guy =~ s/\D//g;                                                               
if ($guy == 0){                                                                
    die("Please enter number for employee, broken");                     
}
my $sides = param('clock');
my $finger =  param('finger');

print $q->start_html(
-title => "Enroll Finger Print".
-style => {-code => $style},
);
print $q->h2("Enrolling Finger...");
if ($sides eq "left"){
    $ssh->connect("172.16.4.10") or $ssh->die_with_error;
    $ssh->auth_publickey("root", "../files/id_rsa.pub", "../files/id_rsa") or $ssh->die_with_error;
    my $chan = $ssh->channel;
    $chan->exec("fprintd-enroll  -f ${finger} ${guy}");
    $ssh->disconnect();
    print $q->h2("Sent request for ", $guy,"'s ", $finger);
    print end_html;
    exit 0;
}

if ($sides eq "right"){
    $ssh->connect("172.16.4.11") or $ssh->die_with_error;
    $ssh->auth_publickey("root", "../files/id_rsa.pub", "../files/id_rsa") or $ssh->die_with_error;
    my $chan = $ssh->channel;
    $chan->exec("fprintd-enroll -f ${finger} ${guy}");
    $ssh->disconnect();
    print "Sent request for ", $guy,"'s ", $finger;
    print end_html;
    exit 0;
}
else{
print $q->h4("Timeclock not selected\n");
print $q->h4("Please select a timeclock to use for finger enrollment.");
exit 1;
}

## Subs

sub get_style {
my $style = <<"EOT";
body {
font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
bgcolor: white;
padding-left: 5%;
}
h2 {
colors: purple;
border-bottom: 1pt solid;
}
h4 {
color: blue;
}
EOT
return $style;
}
```

Comment: For one, the colon after the IP in the ssh commands should not be there. What user is running the httpd daemon, and is it configured to execute the sudo command with no password? Is key authentication configured properly (either no password or perhaps there is an agent running)? Why not use the Net::SSH or Net::SSH::Perl module? Oh, and instead of just exiting, you want to output an HTML page. Never always assume a successful return from the system call.

Comment: Could you explain what you're expecting to happen? The first argument to `system` is the program to execute... What is the command you're hoping Perl would execute?

Comment: @Deathgrip yes shared key auth and sudo are configured. I', I removed the colon I realized I was just typing it the way I scp around. I will try Net::SSH::Perl if this doesn't work

Comment: @derobert based on selections from the previous page I am expecting the correct finger to be enrolled for the correct user.

Comment: @stelicho - As I noted earlier, the script needs to produce HTML output. Simply doing something and exiting will cause the error you are seeing. I believe a one line perl script that contains just the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/perl` will give you the same error message.

Comment: @stelicho - FYI - you can test the script from the command line as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224158/how-can-i-send-post-and-get-data-to-a-perl-cgi-script-via-the-command-line and/or http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#DEBUGGING

Comment: Some distros also have `requiretty` in the /etc/sudoers, so the sudo would likely fail from a CGI running without a TTY.

Comment: @Deathgrip Will do. I understand what you are saying now.

Comment: @jsbillings      ssh -t?

Comment: @stelicho that won't give "sudo" a tty.

Comment: @Deathgrip So I tweaked the script generate HTML output and use Net:SSH2, and to take the params(), and now I am stuck again. Running the script with arguments from the prompt gives me no issues and generates all the HTML in the script. But in the Browser I get just a single "</p>". This makes no sense because I don't even use the <p> tag anywhere.

Comment: You need to be consistent in using `$q->`. Me, I'm OCD and always use what the man page calls the _object oriented_ style. Mixing `$q->start_html` and later just `end_html` is bad form.

Comment: You also have a typo: `print $q->start_html(
-title => "Enroll Finger Print".
-style => {-code => $style},
);`

Should be `print $q->start_html(
-title => "Enroll Finger Print",
-style => {-code => $style},
);`

Comment: I just changed those two. Didn't even see the typo. It still just prints a </p> on screen but the code looks cleaner. I think I am going to try something else, like an external script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a quick HTML form to execute the following code. While not a complete rewrite; and **definitely not complete**, it does work. Notice the addition of the `print $q->header(...)` lines before the `print $q->start_html(...)` lines. If I were to finish cleaning it up, I would remove the calls to `die` and replace with something similar to what is done for a bad number input. In some instances instead of calling die, you may want to send an HTML server error response (5xx) for failed ssh connections/logins. Repeated multiline sections of code should probably be placed into a function. I also didn't produce cleaner HTML output for the clock not being *left* or *right*, like I said this is not what I would consider a complete program. When writing CGI you need to wrap your head around the fact that the output really isn't a terminal or console. You should capture almost every possible failure (logins, connects, queries, command output, etc) and produce HTML (and maybe refresh headers to return back to the original form or another web page) accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                              
#
# vi: set ft=perl syntax=perl noai ts=4 sw=4:       
use CGI qw(:standard -debug);                                                 
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);                          
use Net::SSH2;                                                                
use strict;                                                                    
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();                                                    
my $q = new CGI;                                                              
my $formurl = "http://webhost.example.com/testform.html";
my $lefthost = "leftclock.example.com";
my $righthost = "rightclock.example.com";
my $publickey = "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa2.pub";
my $privatekey = "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa2";
my $username = "user";

my $style = get_style();                                                                                                                                  
my $guy = $q->param('number');                                                    
$guy =~ s/\D//g;                                                               
if ($guy == 0){                                                                
#    die("Please enter number for employee, broken");                     
    print $q->header( -type => "text/html", -Refresh=>"5; URL=$formurl" );
    print $q->start_html( -title => "Bad Number" );
    print $q->h2("Missing Employee Number");
    print "Please return to the the form and enter employee number<BR>\n";
    print "If you are not redirected in 5 seconds, click on the following link.<BR>\n";
    print $q->a({-href => $formurl},"$formurl");
    print $q->end_html;
    exit 0;
}

my $sides = $q->param('clock');
if ($sides ne "left" && $sides ne "right" ) {
    print $q->header( -type => "text/html", -Refresh=>"5; URL=$formurl" );
    print $q->start_html( -title => "Bad Clock" );
    print $q->h2("Incorrect Clock Chosen");
    print "Please return to the form and enter \"left\" or \"right\" for clock.<BR>\n";
    print "If you are not redirected in 5 seconds, click on the following link.<BR>\n";
    print $q->a({-href => $formurl},"$formurl");
    print $q->end_html;
    exit 0;
}

my $finger =  $q->param('finger');
#
# Add code here to validate value entered for finger
# Follow logic from $sides and $guy above
#

#
# At this point all the field values are validated and we can begin
# to process
#

print $q->header(-type => "text/html" );

print $q->start_html(
-title => "Enroll Finger Print",
-style => {-code => $style},
);
print $q->h2("Enrolling Finger...");
if ($sides eq "left"){
    $ssh2->connect($lefthost) or die;
    if (! $ssh2->auth_publickey($username, $publickey, $privatekey, undef)) {
        print $ssh2->error;
    }
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel;

    $chan->exec("fprintd-enroll  -f ${finger} ${guy}");
    $chan->send_eof;
    while (<$chan>) {
        chomp;
        print "line read: $_</BR>\n";
    }

    $chan->close;

    $ssh2->disconnect();
    print $q->h2("Sent request for " . $guy . "'s " . "$finger");
    print $q->end_html;
    exit 0;
}

if ($sides eq "right"){
    $ssh2->connect($righthost) or die;
    if (! $ssh2->auth_publickey($username, $publickey, $privatekey, undef)) {
        print $ssh2->error;
    }
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel;

    $chan->exec("fprintd-enroll  -f ${finger} ${guy}");
    $chan->send_eof;
    while (<$chan>) {
        chomp;
        print "line read: $_</BR>\n";
    }

    $chan->close;

    $ssh2->disconnect();
    print $q->h2("Sent request for " . $guy . "'s " . "$finger");
    print $q->end_html;
    exit 0;
}
else{
print $q->h4("Timeclock not selected\n");
print $q->h4("Please select a timeclock to use for finger enrollment.");
exit 1;
}

## Subs

sub get_style {
my $style = <<"EOT";
body {
font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
bgcolor: white;
padding-left: 5%;
}
h2 {
colors: purple;
border-bottom: 1pt solid;
}
h4 {
color: blue;
}
EOT
return $style;
}
```

Comment: The only reason I haven't replied is because I am still testing it out to see how it works. I had been believing you about the html but i didn't realize how much html I needed.

Comment: `$chan->exec("fprintd-enroll  -f ${finger} ${guy}");
      $chan->send_eof;
        while (<$chan>) 
          chomp;
            print "line read: $_</BR>\";
        }` Was what I was missing to get the script to run, but I understand about returning html for each action and not expecting it to automatically print what it's doing. Thank you!